# Set up permissions on file in mounted CIFS share - NIO.2

Tags: java, java-7, file-permissions, cifs, nio2

I am trying to add a set of attributes at creation time as in the following example.
This code creates a new file on a POSIX file system with specific permissions ("rw-rw-r--") in mounted CIFS share.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path new_path = Paths.get("/mnt/test/new_file.txt");

        System.out.println(new_path.getFileSystem().supportedFileAttributeViews().contains("posix"));

        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw-r--");
        FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);

        try {
            Files.createFile(new_path, attr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

After run the simple code, the file was created but the permissions for it looks

```
rwxrwSrwx 1 root root        0 May  5  2014 new_file.txt
```

instead of what I needed (look in the code 'rw-rw-r--')

Can someone help me with that issue?

Comment: The piece of code works well. We found that privileges on this mounted drive were too restricted.